# Font Size Problems

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website and having some problems with font sizes. I can make it look good while on a computer, but on a phone the font sizes gets weird.

When on a phone, the 'Back' buttons get really small and the paragraphs gets enlarged, and I can't get it to look the same as on a computer.

Html

```
<div class="Class" id="ID">
    <br><br>
    <h3><u>Title</u></h3>
    <p>Some random text</p>
    <a href="#top">Back</a>         
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Class
{
    font-size:15px;
    padding:20px;
    width:600px;
}
.Class p
{
    font-size:20px;
}
.Class a
{
    color:black;
    display:block;
    width:80px;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:24px;
}
.Class a, visited
{
    color:black;
}
.Class a:hover
{
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
}
```

The result is on a phone is that  gets small and the paragraphs gets bigger.
Not sure what's relevant, I'm still a novice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have font sizes in pixels, so they look smaller on the phone. You have two options here, either define larger pixel sizes for smaller devices using media queries, or use `em`'s instead of pixels.

option 1 example :

```
.Class {
    font-size: 15px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
    .Class {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

Option 2 Example:

```
.Class {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: That is up to you in terms of how you want to approach your project. em gives more control to the user. Most of the time this is a good thing, e.g. people that can't see very well will have a browser setting for larger font size, and em will allow that larger font size. Pixels are more rigid (basically you force users to see a specific size, period.). However I still use pixels because ems can sometimes look weird and things may start overflowing on top of each other if you don't do everything else right. You can also use REM or just percentage too. There's many ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use em instead of pixels.
I you don't know what em means:
Em is relatively to the font-size. So when you have 2em it is 2 times the size of the current font.

So you have to change your CSS to:

```
    .Class
    {
        font-size: 0.938em;
    }
```

And:

```
    .Class p
    {
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }
```

And:

```
    .Class a
    {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
```

Or if you want to copy and paste easily:

```
    .Class
    {
        font-size:0.938em;
        padding:20px;
        width:600px;
    }
    .Class p
    {
        font-size:1.25em;
    }
    .Class a
    {
        color:black;
        display:block;
        width:80px;
        margin:0;
        padding:10px;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .Class a, visited
    {
        color:black;
    }
    .Class a:hover
    {
        background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    }
```

If you want to know how much px is in em you can look it up here:
http://pxtoem.com/